# Print Seperator files on Server 2016 not working in an alternate location

Tags: windows, printing, windows-server-2016, shared-printers

With Server 2008 R2 and 2012R2, we were able to have the *.sep files stored in a location outside of System32, C:\SepFiles\coversheet.sep.  As long as the folder had the name SepFiles it was working.

We recently installed a new 2016 Server and have our Windows 10 machines installed with printers from the server.  They are not getting the cover sheets.

I could find a tech note regarding the SepFiles in Server 2012 and 2012R2, nothing for print services on 2016.

I know that I should be able to put the *.sep file in the system32 folder, but am hesitant as we had issues with 2012R2 deleting the *.sep files from the system32 folder without warning.  The alternate location of c:\SepFiles has been rock solid without issues.

Has anyone had any luck with *.sep files outside of the system32 folder on Server 2016?

Thank you.

Comment: I've no experience with this at all, but have you checked permissions on the folder to make sure the services involved in printing have appropriate access to the folders?